# Can you find and replace URL's in a formula with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a summary sheet for teachers to pull in all their student's data. Each column is a different student and has a different URL for the student's file. I have over 50 teachers and 850+ students. I am trying to find a way using google apps script to find and replace the URLs in a column. I have this code so far, and I can see the 'baseLink' and the 'replaceLink' in the log, but I cannot figure out what to do to get them to replace. I'm attaching a snapshot of the spreadsheet I'm using in case that helps explain my issue better. You can see I use the importrange formula to pull in the URLs and those are what need to be changed. I do need to read through all the columns, but I'm happy just learning how to do one column first.  Thanks for any help!
[image]

[image]

This is the code I have, with a line of pseudo code where I need help:

```
function UpdateColumnLinks() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getRange('G1:G76');
  var baseLink = ss.getRange('R2').getValue(); //This is the URL of a spreadsheet I want to replace that is in the formula
  var replaceLink = ss.getRange('S10').getValue();  //This is the URL of a spreadsheet I want to see in the formula

  Logger.log(baseLink)
  Logger.log(replaceLink)

  for i = 0; i<range.length; i++ {

  pseudo code:  find baseLink in range and replace with replaceLink

  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with an example of a string with a baseLink and a replaceLink

Answer (score 1):

Replacing Links in a Spreadsheet

Rich Text Links:

```
function UpdateColumnLinks() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,3,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var dvs=rg.getRichTextValues();
  var rl=sh.getRange(1,1).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();replacement link
  var ls=SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(rl).build();
  for(var i=0;i<dvs.length;i++) {
    var link=dvs[i][0]=ls;
  }
  rg.setRichTextValues(dvs);
}
```

[RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#setText(String))

[Class RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)

Formula Links:

```
function UpdateColumnLinks1() {
  const sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const rl=sh.getRange(1,1).getFormula();
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,3,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vs=rg.getFormulas();
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    r[0]=rl;
  });
  rg.setFormulas(vs);
}
```

Your specific case:

```
function UpdateColumnLinks() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=ss.getRange('G1:G76);
  var fA=rg.getFormulas();
  var rl=ss.getRange('S10').getFormula();
  fA.forEach(function(r){r[0]=rl;});
  rg.setFormulas(fA);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. You showed me the RichTextValueBuilder and the Class RichTextValue. I don't understand them. When I run the second function (Formula Links:), it deletes everything in the column. I don't understand why. When I run the third (Your specific case:) it throws a ReferenceError  on this line:  fA.forEach(function(r){r[0]=rl;}); - rl is not defined.  I did put add the missing tic mark on the 3rd line ('G1:G76'). Again, thank you for taking the time to respond and explain. I have so much to learn.

Comment: I meant to ask - what does this function do? function(r){r[0]=rl;}) - Thank you.

Comment: This `fA.forEach(function(r){r[0]=rl;});` is an Array.forEach() method.  It just loop through array.  The r is one element of the array in this situation it is a row of a single column and it's just setting every element in each row of the column to rl;  [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Your Reference links are SO useful. Thank you. I figured out that rl is replaceLink (I think?). And it appears to pass back an empty array:  Snippet from log:  [=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQ3OVZqRYndOX5lJJ7phaB_yO8K9JIoRby3mt78IgZ0/edit?usp=drivesdk","Profile Data!T6")], [=importrange
[20-06-06 09:25:19:891 EDT] [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

Comment: It's getting the original formulas from the cells values; however, when the forEach runs and its reads the replacement link - it appears not to pick up that value and passes in empty array values and makes it 'look' like everything was deleted.

Comment: I forgot to rename replaceLink to rl

Comment: Yes, I did get that, thanks. However, it's still not working. It's still passing blank values. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: What is in S10?

Comment: S10 is the 'new' URL that needs to replace the URL that is originally in the column with formulas.  The entire formula looks like this: =importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cuaU9E8tWEsVzz0durw3sZ7jD4_gID5_m6Ei4ZgA/edit?usp=drivesdk","Profile Data!e5")  And the only piece being replaced is the URL piece. As an example, it's being replaced with only this portion: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DYO7xGwa_-QyvPaiGuSDkyyl2rTkcRk5JO82Ic/edit?usp=drivesdk"  I didn't mean for those to be actual links - sorry. I hope that helps.

Comment: Well then you have to figure out what this `var rl=ss.getRange('S10').getFormula();` line is on your own.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me out with it Cooper. It is appreciated.